# Changing a variable changes the copy of the variable

Tags: python-3.x, list

The problem I am attempting to solve is a question on leetcode (link: 
https://leetcode.com/problems/rotting-oranges/)
When I try to change the variable grid, it changes the copy p.

I looked at similar questions on stack overflow and tried all the solution which didn't work. I also attempted to troubleshoot the problem myself using print.

```
import copy
class Solution:
    def orangesRotting(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        if grid == []:
            return 0
        s = []
        t = 0
        while True:
            p = copy.copy(list(grid.copy()[:]))
            print(p, grid)
            for r, l in enumerate(grid):
                for c, v in enumerate(l):
                    if v == 2:
                        if c-1>=0 and grid[r][c-1] == 1:
                            s.append([r, c-1])
                        if c+1<len(l) and grid[r][c+1] == 1:
                            s.append([r, c+1])
                        if r-1>=0 and grid[r-1][c] == 1:
                            s.append([r-1, c])
                        if r+1<len(grid) and grid[r+1][c] == 1:
                            s.append([r+1, c])
            print(p, s)
            for i in s:
                grid[i[0]][i[1]] = 2
                print(p, i)
            print(p, grid)
            if p == grid:
                for i in grid:
                    for j in i:
                        if j == 1:
                            return -1
                return t
            print(t)
            t+=1
            s= []
```

Near the bottom of the code, when I change the variable grid, the variable p gets changed as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented, `copy.copy()` only makes a shallow copy - the lists themselves are different objects, but they (initially at least) still point to the same objects. So if those objects are mutable, the results mutating one will indeed be visible thru both lists indeed.

What you want here is `copy.deepcopy()`, which will recursively creates (deep) copies of all objects in the list.